# Send XML in message service bus and parse it in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

As I am a beginner on azue, I would like to know the procedure to follow for the following process:
sending an xml with a service bus message and receiving and parse it with logic app.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used 2 logic apps in this case where 1 sends an XML message through the service bus and the other receives it.

**The flow of Logic App - 1** (Sending XML message to Service bus)

[image]

**The flow of Logic App - 2** (Receiving XML message from Service bus and parsing it)

You can convert XML to JSON and then use Parse_JSON to parse it.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]

**Codeview of Logic app - 1**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Send_message": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "ContentData": "@{base64(outputs('XML_Content'))}",
                        "SessionId": "@{utcNow()}"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('queue1'))}/messages"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "XML_Content": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "XML_Content": {
                "inputs": "<note>\n<to>Tove</to>\n<from>Jani</from>\n<heading>Reminder</heading>\n<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>\n</note>",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "servicebus": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus-1",
                    "connectionName": "servicebus-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Codeview of Logic app - 2**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(xml(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])))",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "note": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "body": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "from": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "heading": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "to": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_message_is_received_in_a_queue_(auto-complete)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['servicebus_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('queue1'))}/messages/head",
                    "queries": {
                        "queueType": "Main"
                    }
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Second",
                    "interval": 1
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "servicebus_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/servicebus-2",
                    "connectionName": "servicebus-2",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SubId>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/servicebus"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not answer at all to my request.

Comment: @Dev, Apologies for the confusion. I have updated my answer

Comment: No problem ;-) could you show me plz the configuration for the service bus (content, xml..) thank you

Comment: @Dev You meant the API connection for service bus in logic apps? However, I have added my code view so that you can reproduce the same in your environment.

Comment: yes i get it the codeview, i would understand: befor the logic app step receive xml, i would like to see the configuration of the service bus with xml message

Comment: @Dev Here is my service bus trigger for receive XML https://i.imgur.com/0R5g69p.png

Comment: i mean the configuration of the service bus not the service bus trigger in logic apps, you think do you understand my request ? i woulk like to see the message with xml in the service bus

Comment: @Dev So here is the thing, when a message is sent to service bus, the logic app 2 trigger automatically reads the message that has come to the queue. You can able to see its details after execution. Please refer https://i.imgur.com/rojWwqg.png. Let me know if I got off track.

Comment: it's clear but i would understand before logic app, how the message arrived to the service bus (the configuration of the service bus with this message), the xml is in the message service bus ?

Comment: @Dev Yes, it is in the content section. The configuration of receiving the message has an unlying structure in logic apps.

Comment: you can tell me where is it the content section ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/rojWwqg.png you can able to see this only after the run